# Ajax and JavaScript, how to POST array *without* using JQuery?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm calling a PHP function via Ajax:

```
var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
ajax.open("POST", "file.php", true);
ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

ajax.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200){
        var returnVal = JSON.parse(ajax.responseText);

        // do stuff here //
    }
}   
ajax.send('term=' + javaScriptArray);
```

All is fine, and it works a treat when sending a single value, but falls short when I try and POST an array.

In my PHP function, I am checking to see if the POST variable is an array:

```
is_array($_POST['term']);
```

but it *always* returns false.

Echoing the value prints something like:

```
value1,value2,value3
```

but as a single string, not as an array.

[This SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143624/sending-arrays-via-ajax-json-without-jquery) has an answer that does not send as an array, but rather as multiple different variables, and uses GET:

```
ajax.open("GET","myserver.com/myfunction.php?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3",true);
```

The data I am sending is always variable in number of items, and so sending as an array is the best option for me. A simple `is_array()` in the PHP is a lot simpler for what I am doing.

I've looked at setting multiple variables:

```
for(var i = 0; i < argument.length; i++){
    postString += 'arg' + i + '=' + argument[i] + '&';
}
ajax.send(postString);
```

but that still doesn't really get what I'm trying for (again with multiple variables).

I've also tried sending them all with the same variable name:

```
ajax.send('arg=one&arg=two&arg=three');
```

but each successive one overwrites its predecessor.

**I am not interested in solutions using JQuery.** I don't need that whole library, this is the only thing I need.

**EDIT 1**

I would also like to keep it as `POST`.

Comment: JSON.stringify works without jquery

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For an argument to be considered an array it must use `[]` notation

```
var postArray = new Array();
for(var i = 0; i < argument.length; i++){
    postArray[i] = 'arg[]=' + encodeURIComponent(argument[i]);
}
ajax.send(postArray.join('&'));
```

Comment: That'll do it. I didn't know about the `[]` syntax for posting an array, Much thanks!

Comment: I'd +1 again if I could for the `.join()` - I've never seen that before.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make PHP clear, that it is an array you are sending. You usually can do this by adding `[]`, as you would in PHP. So in your example, try this:

```
ajax.send('arg[]=one&arg[]=two&arg[]=three');
```

Comment: Yes, I noticed that in the PHP it will always be receiving an array now, even if just a single value. Thanks.