# Pass Array from JS to PHP and create SESSION variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, session

I want to pass an array from JS to PHP and then use it there, I gather the values in JS and send them to a fnother file where I try turn it into a $_SESSION variable but when I do a var_dump on this it gives me a string with comma seperated values. Is there a better way of doing this?

My JS:

```
var value_1 = document.getElementById("value_1").value;
var value_2 = document.getElementById("value_2").value;
var value_3 = document.getElementById("value_3").value;
var value_4 = document.getElementById("value_4").value;
var value_5 = document.getElementById("value_5").value;

var values = [];
values.push(value_1);
values.push(value_2);
values.push(value_3);
values.push(value_4);
values.push(value_5);

var formData = new FormData();
formData.append("values", values);
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        // success
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "myfile.php", true);
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

PHP:

```
if(isset($_POST['values'])){
    $_SESSION['values'] = $_POST['values'];
}
```

Comment: Are you sure it gives you a string with comma separated values, or is it more like `["value_1", "value_2", "value_3"]`?

Comment: yeah I do `var_dump($_SESSION['values']);` and it returns `C:\wamp64\www\<directory>\<file>:<line>:string 'value1,value2,value3,value4,value5`

Comment: You could stringify the array to a json string that you post to PHP, which you then decode in PHP.

Comment: Can anyone tell me what converts it to a string is it the JS sending it or is it setting it to a session? Like is it converted to a string already when the PHP file picks it up as a post?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sending Arrays via Ajax/JSON without JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30143624/sending-arrays-via-ajax-json-without-jquery)

Comment: @executable I don't get your flagging as a possible duplicate *and* an answer. I feel the flag should be removed. That isn't fair for others later who might want to post more answers.

Comment: Sorry, how can I remove it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should convert your array into JSON, like :

```
var value_1 = document.getElementById("value_1").value;
var value_2 = document.getElementById("value_2").value;
var value_3 = document.getElementById("value_3").value;
var value_4 = document.getElementById("value_4").value;
var value_5 = document.getElementById("value_5").value;

var values = [];
values.push(value_1);
values.push(value_2);
values.push(value_3);
values.push(value_4);
values.push(value_5);

var json_upload = "values=" + JSON.stringify({values});
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("POST", "myfile.php");
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xmlhttp.send(json_upload);
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['values'])){
    $_SESSION['values'] = $_POST['values'];
}
```

Comment: I did this and just changed one line `$_SESSION['values'] = json_decode($_POST['values']);` and got the desired result

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with your original code was using an array as the value argument for [FormData.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append) (should be a string, which the JavaScript engine has type-cast your array to in your case).

If you instead append each value with the same key-name suffixed with an empty pair of square brackets (e.g. `values[]`), PHP will automatically form these into a numeric array for you.

JavaScript:

```
var formData = new FormData();
for(var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
    formData.append("values[]", document.getElementById("value_" + i).value);
}
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
    if(this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200){
        // success
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("POST", "myfile.php", true);
xmlhttp.send(formData);
```

PHP:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(isset($_POST['values'])){
    $_SESSION['values'] = $_POST['values'];
}
```

Answer (score -3):

The better way is to use jQuery $.ajax() function:

_this.sendAjaxRequest = function(url, data, callback, errorCallback) {

```
    var _type = $.inArray($.type(data), ['string', 'object']) > -1 ? 'post' : 'get';

    var request  = $.ajax({
        'url'      : url,
        'type'     : _type,
        'dataType' : 'json',
        'data'     : data,
        'cache'    : false,
        'success'  : function(response) {
            if (typeof callback != 'undefined' && callback) {
                callback.call(_this, response);
                return;
            }
        },
        'error'    : function(response) {
            if (typeof errorCallback != 'undefined' && errorCallback) {
                errorCallback.call(_this, response);
                return;
            }
        }
    });
};
```

You could use JSON object as data variable.

Comment: He doesn't use jQuery

Comment: _"The better way is to use jQuery $.ajax()"_ - Why would including a 100kb bloated js library be a "better" way?

Comment: Why is this "better"? Include an external dependency when it's not in use anywhere else?

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, I might come back to use jQuery.

Comment: @PaddyHallihan - If you want to learn proper development, I would stick to what you got now and sort the issues out instead. You don't want to be a "library"-developer (a developer that doesn't actually knows the language, but only a few libraries). There's nothing wrong with using tools and libraries, but including a 100kb lib just for this is overkill and bad for the end user (that needs to download all that extra bloat).

Comment: Better - because it saves time and makes code simple and you don't have to develop and support your own wrappers over XMLHttpRequest.
For educational purposes - it is good to learn deeper, of course.